# Broken links when rendering notes as endnotes using sepfootnotes

Tags: hyperref, endnotes

I'm using the `sepfootnotes` package to store my notes in a separate file and retrieve them as endnotes. I have a really solid setup, and everything is working well except for one thing: when I click on a footnote, it brings me back up to the first page, instead of the expected behaviour of going down to the endnote in its dedicated section. This seems to be an issue only when rendering notes as endnotes, and does not seem to be a factor when using footnotes, according to my tests. I get the same results when storing the notes within the document or in a separate file. When rendering notes using footnotes it makes no difference whether the content is above or below the note, as was mentioned in some other thread. It also makes no difference whether or not I include the `\section` tag. Here are the examples I used in my tests:

Using footnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Some dummy text on a first page.
\newpage

Some text that requires elaboration using a note.\sepfootnote{x}
\sepfootnotecontent{x}{Blah.}

\end{document}
```

Using endnotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\newendnotes{a}
\anotecontent{x}{Blah.}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Some dummy text on a first page.
\newpage

Some text that requires elaboration using a note.\anote{x}

\section{Notes}
\theanotes

\end{document}
```

Could this be a bug within the `sepfootnotes` package? Or am I doing something wrong here?